# Can not find the specified object with X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I'm trying to load a file that contains the secret key to access to `Google Calendar API`. [Following this tutorial.](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/)
For doing this I've created this code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("client_secret.json", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I've uploaded `client_secret.json` file inside my solution, this is the path of the file: `"...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Calendar\Calendar\bin\Debug\client_secret.json"`

but seems that the code can't locate the file and return this error:

> Can not find the specified object with X509Certificate2

I also set the property `Always copy` on `Copy in the output directory` on the file to read.

Comment: Did you try to add a full path to the key?

Comment: @MegaTron yes, same error. I tried to put it in `c:\`

Comment: ok, is it Web(ASP) application?

Comment: @MegaTron Nope is a wpf + c# app

Comment: @Dillinger are you sure the file contains a valid certificate?

Comment: @user469104 I answered your question on the MegaTron answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a bit 'of headaches I was able to understand where wrong, as I said in the comments I generate the certificate by:

> The first step that I did is create the API for Google Calendar, later I clicked on "create credentials" and selected "Service account", choosing the API that I've created before and the key type as json.

this certificate is different against the key the the `X509Certificate2` waiting, so the correct step to do is:

**1**. Click on Manage Service Account on the Developer Console, this workding is on the right of the credentials tab, just a little 'over to your projects list.

**2**. A new window appears, you need to click on the three dots next to the project you want to create the key. (The three dots are on the right).

**3**. A pop-up menu appear, and then, you need to click `Create Key`.

**4**. Chose the P12 format, and then click on Create.

**5**. Save the file downloaded on a folder and link them in your code, in particular:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

note that `key.p12` is the name of the file of the certificate, and `notasecret` is the default password that appear just a bit later of the step 4, in other word is the password associated to the certificate.

So my code seems to find the file and read it correctly without display any errors.

Thanks anyway to [MegaTron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275342/megatron) that have aroused in me the doubt that the certificate was somehow not right.

Comment: Thank you for your tips (@Dillinger), they helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`MachineKeySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags.aspx). It means that need to use the local computer store for the key:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("client_secret.json", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Comment: Unfortunately same error.. I tried also to another hdd drive as: `var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"A:\client_secret.json", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);`

Comment: @Dillinger How did you create json key? As I understood you had used Google Developers Console, right?

Comment: The first step that I did is create the API for Google Calendar, later I clicked on "create credentials" and selected "Service account", choosing the API that I've created before and the key type as json. There is also a P12 format, you think that `X509Certificate2` working only with P12 format? UPDATE: just tried now with P12, still get the same. Really I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: @Dillinger Very strange. Did you try to use all flags`MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable`?

Comment: I post an answer, finally I have managed to solve the problem. Thanks